# Loading from multiple databases in Django custom command

Tags: django

If I am creating a Django custom command, can I get data from more than one database? In `C:/Project/myproject/settings.py`, I have:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

Then in `C:/Project/myproject/myapp/management/commands/mycommand.py`, I have:

```
users = User.objects.all()
```

Where `User` is defined in `C:/Project/myapp/models.py`.

But what if I have several databases, called `db1.sqlite3`, `db2.sqlite3`, `db3.sqlite3` etc., and I want to load all `User` objects from all these databases in my custom command? Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

From [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#manually-selecting-a-database):

> You can select the database for a QuerySet at any point in the
>   QuerySet “chain.” Just call using() on the QuerySet to get another
>   QuerySet that uses the specified database.

You just define more databases in settings.py, give them names and pass that name into using('db_name').